# Ajax with form method as post in node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have an issue with Ajax in a form with node.js, I'm developing a simple node.js currency converter application and populating the data on the frontend (HTML) using Ajax. However it's not working, any help is seriously appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In the frontend script, the `form` tag has `POST` as method, but it is of no use. Can you try changing the first parameter of `xmlhttp.open()` from `GET` to `POST`?

Comment: I did try using POST in xmlhttp.open() and i get empty data with xmlhttp.responseText and home.html goes blank as in it contains no text instead of home.html

Comment: You also have your `response.end()` function commented. Uncomment it.

Comment: Remove `response.end` and `response.writeHead` from bottom, and move it to where you are calculating `store`.

Comment: If you look further below the Commented response.end() , you can see my uncommented response.end(store); (Im trying to send the data "store" to front end using AJAX here)

Comment: I tried that but however i get an error  : response.writeHead is not a function
   Converter-application-node/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:489:18

Comment: Well, the problem lies with same variable name, `response` used for handling request and for making http request to 3rd party api. That's why it can't find writeHead function.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don't understand

Comment: Please try to use the code in my answer as I can't write the full code in comments.

Comment: Please spare me the embarrassment but im relatively new to node.js and my question is why would we post the result to a new html page ?

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Frontend

Change this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:9099/", true);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost:9099/", true);
```

as your backend server accepts `POST` for getting the answer.

## 2. Backend

Remove `response.end` and `response.writeHead` from bottom, and move it to where you are calculating `store`.

Your final code:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  switch (request.method) {
    case 'POST':
      if (request.url === "/") {
        var requestBody = '';
        request.on('data', function(data) {
          requestBody += data;
          if (requestBody.length > 1e7) {
            response.writeHead(413, {
              'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            });
            response.end('Request Entity is too large');
          }
        });

        request.on('end', function(data) {
          console.log(requestBody);
          var formData = qs.parse(requestBody);

          var requestBofy = '';

          // I renamed the callback parameter to response2
          https.get('https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml?8f65cd5d1af1727c40d2a89a31c6a0f1', function(response2) {
            if (response2.statusCode >= 200 && response2.statusCode < 400) {
              response2.on('data', function(data_) {
                requestBofy += data_.toString();
              });
              response2.on('end', function() {
                console.log(requestBofy);
                parser.parseString(requestBofy, function(err, result) {
                  console.log('FINISHED', err, result);

                  var xml = requestBofy;

                  var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
                  parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
                    var jFile = JSON.stringify(result);

                    var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(jFile);
                    var rateHUF = parsedResponse['gesmes:Envelope']['Cube'][0]['Cube'][0]['Cube'][6]['$'].rate;
                    var rateINR = parsedResponse['gesmes:Envelope']['Cube'][0]['Cube'][0]['Cube'][22]['$'].rate;
                    var store = 'No value';
                    if (formData.vSelectedValue == 'HUF' && formData.vSelectedValue2 == 'INR') {
                      store = Math.round(formData.vFirstNo * (rateINR / rateHUF));
                    } else {
                      store = Math.round(formData.vFirstNo * (rateHUF / rateINR));
                    }

                    // Your response should end here
                    response.writeHead(200, {
                      "Content-Type": "text/html"
                    });
                    response.end('Your Answer: ' + store);

                  });

                });
              });
            }
          });

        });
      } else {
        response.writeHead(404, {
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        response.end('404 - Page not found');
      }

      break;
    case 'GET':
      if (request.url === "/") {

        getFileContent(response, 'public/home.html', 'text/html');

      } else {
        response.writeHead(404, {
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        response.end('404 - Page not found');

      }
      break;

    default:
      response.writeHead(404, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });
      response.end('404 - Page not found');

  }

}).listen(9099);
```

Comment: Please spare me the embarrassment but im relatively new to node.js and my question is why would we post the result to a new html page ?       response.writeHead(200, {
                      "Content-Type": "text/html"
                    });
                    response.end('Your Answer: ' + store);
Instead of posting the data on to the home.html in a text box ? because the whole point is to fill the text box with the result , so shouldn't we use "home.html" in response.write() ?